# Change Icons of Safari-Tabs

Tags: safari, icon, nas

I have a Synology NAS and there I have several services running. E.g. my Unifi Controller, Home Assistant, Plex, ... So all of them have the same IP address, but a different port. Safari though thinks it's all the same and gives everything the same favicon. Is there a way to change that?

Thanks, Georg

[image]

Comment: There's a handy extension for Chrome that can do this: [Tab Modifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai) - Maybe there's something similar for Safari.

Comment: the favicon.ico file is fetched by the browser from the web server you are connecting to. So you may be able to change the icon at the source since it is on your NAS but then you would change all of them all at once since all the pages you are accessing are on the same web server. Failing @Joonas suggestion you may be out of luck.